# How do I redirect relative to the express application root?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to make my app so that it can be mounted at some location other than `/`. When I read the docs for express-4.x’s [`res.redirect()`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect), it says I have three options:

1. Absolute URI (`http://example.org/path/nested`)
2. Host-relative (`/path/nested`)
3. URI-relative (`nested`)

I don’t see any option for application-relative redirects.

Example of how an app might  be mounted within another:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');

const app = express();
module.exports = app;

const subApp = express();
app.use('/subApp', subApp);

subApp.get('/blah/*', (req, res) => {
    if (/dee$/.test(req.url)) {
        res.end('end');
    } else {
        res.redirect('dee');
    }
});
```

How do I redirect to the root URI of `subApp` without requiring the code in `subApp` to know its mountpoint? Maybe there is a way I can construct it from information in `req`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this manually using [`req.baseUrl`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.baseUrl) (I’m using express-4.x). For example:

```
subApp.get('/blah/*', (req, res) => {
    if (/dee$/.test(req.url)) {
        res.end('end');
    } else {
        res.redirect(req.baseUrl + '/dee');
    }
});
```